# Printing an ArrayList from a different function

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

The objective of this code is to take in user input and display them as a single record. I wrote a menu followed by 2 methods, set and display, have used the Scanner class to populate the arrayList but am not able to print them using the display method.

Here is the code, please tell me how to fix this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Records2 {

   static ArrayList information = new ArrayList();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int choice;
      do {
         System.out.println("1.Add \n 2.Delete \n 3.Update \n 4.Show \n Exit");

         //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         //int choice;
         System.out.println("Enter your Choice : ");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         choice = sc.nextInt();

         switch (choice) {

         case 1: System.out.println("Getting ready to Add a Record ");
            set();
            break;

         case 2: System.out.println("Getting ready to Delete a Record ");
            //delete();
            break;

         case 3: System.out.println("Getting ready to Update a Record ");
            //update();
            break;

         case 4: System.out.println("Here is your record ");
            display();
            break;

         case 5: System.out.println("Out we go.");
            System.exit(0);
            //exit();
            break;

         default: System.out.println("Try again");
            break;
         } 

      } while ( choice > 5 || choice < 1 );

   }

   public static void set() {

      System.out.println("Please enter the ID, Name and Address of the person \n");

      Scanner readId = new Scanner(System.in);
      int ID = readId.nextInt();

      Scanner readName = new Scanner(System.in);
      String name = readName.nextLine();

      Scanner readAddress = new Scanner(System.in);
      String address = readAddress.nextLine();

      //ArrayList information = new ArrayList();
      information.add(ID);
      information.add(name);
      information.add(address);
   }

   public static void display() {

      System.out.println("here is your list" + information);
      //how to differentiate from one set to another?
   }

}
```

Comment: How are you stuck? Where's your attempt to print out the list? Why can't you just print out the information ArrayList using a for loop?

Comment: Print your error stack..

Comment: What is option #4 expected to show? The last set result?

Comment: @sp00m The whole record. Or the record the user enters in that session.

Comment: **AGAIN**, how are you stuck? Again, why can't you just print your ArrayList items using a for loop? And why are you ignoring my question?

Comment: @user1502178 Then your code is fine, am I wrong? What does not behave as you expect?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels because there was some error using information.length in the loop, and I thought maybe it can be printed in just one line.

Comment: @sp00m It doesnt print the list after you add something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of your while loop!

```
while ( choice > 5 || choice < 1 );
```

The code will come out of loop after you select choice = 1 which is for set()

So the display is never called.

Use : `while ( choice > 0 && choice < 6)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Records2 {

    static ArrayList<Person> information = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;

        do {
            System.out.println("\n-------------------------------\n Enter your Choice : ");
            System.out.println("1.Add \n 2.Delete \n 3.Update \n 4.Show \n 5.Exit");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = sc.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Getting ready to Add a Record ");
                    set();
                    break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Getting ready to Delete a Record. Enter id - ");
                int choice2 = sc.nextInt();
                delete(choice2);
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Getting ready to Update a Record ");
                // update();
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.println("Here is your record ");
                display();
                break;

            case 5:
                System.out.println("Out we go.");
                System.exit(0);
                // exit();
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Try again");
                break;
            }

        } while ( choice > 1 || choice < 5 );

    }

    public static void set() {

        System.out.println("Please enter the ID, Name and Address of the person \n");

        Scanner readId = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ID = readId.nextInt();

        Scanner readName = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = readName.nextLine();

        Scanner readAddress = new Scanner(System.in);
        String address = readAddress.nextLine();

        // ArrayList information = new ArrayList();

        Person person=new Person();
        person.setID(ID);
        person.setName(name);
        person.setAddress(address);

        information.add(person);



    }

    public static void display() {

        System.out.println("here is your list" + information);
        // how to differentiate from one set to another?
    }

    public static void delete(int passedid) {

//      System.out.println("here is your list" + information);
        // how to differentiate from one set to another?
        System.out.println("Before Deleting - "+information);
        Iterator<Person> it=information.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Person p =   it.next();
            if(p.getID()==passedid){
                it.remove();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("AfterDeleting -"+information);

    }


}

class Person{

    int ID;
    String name;
    String address;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }
     public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [ID=" + ID + ", name=" + name + ", address=" + address
                + "]";
    }



}
```

Here it the output -

```
 -------------------------------
 Enter your Choice : 
1.Add 
 2.Delete 
 3.Update 
 4.Show 
 5.Exit
1
Getting ready to Add a Record 
Please enter the ID, Name and Address of the person 

1
A
AA

-------------------------------
 Enter your Choice : 
1.Add 
 2.Delete 
 3.Update 
 4.Show 
 5.Exit
1
Getting ready to Add a Record 
Please enter the ID, Name and Address of the person 

2
B
BB

-------------------------------
 Enter your Choice : 
1.Add 
 2.Delete 
 3.Update 
 4.Show 
 5.Exit
2
Getting ready to Delete a Record. Enter id - 
1
Before Deleting - [Person [ID=1, name=A, address=AA], Person [ID=2, name=B, address=BB]]
After Deleing - [Person [ID=2, name=B, address=BB]]
```

Comment: The information variable a static ArrayList variable, there's only one, and so there is no need for this.

Comment: But what if the user only wants to view the records?

Comment: In that case you should not exist the program.As you are storing it in the ArrayList at run time.

Comment: @NinadPingale Ah! Right, so I need something that goes back to displaying the menu once the information is added. Right?

Comment: Yes, the loop part did the trick. Very witty! 
But moving forward, the requirements for Update and Delete are to search an ID and then Update or delete it. Any idea how do I proceed to that?

Comment: Pass Id to a method, loop trhough arraylist, when Id matches modify other properties in the list using setter method. for delete `remove` object from arraylist.

Comment: OK, but the thing that is not clear to me yet is, I need to alter the two associated values (name and address) with the id too, how do I achieve that?